# Get Function() result as Control

Tags: excel, userform, vba

***Background:***

I needed a function to correlate Controls efficiently based on a STD name and the text analyzed. IG:

 **a)** Some other input throws the variable "mytext"

 **b)** If the ListBox1.Value has "mytext" then I have to relate it with ToggleButton1

**Approach:**

I made the following function which ***partially*** works

Code:

```
Private Function RelateControl_ToggleVsList(ToggleCtrl As Control) As Control
Dim ItemControl As Control
Dim myControl As Object
    For Each ItemControl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ItemControl) = "ListBox" Then ' 1. If TypeName(ItemControl) = "Label"
    'text lenghts const 13 for ListBox_TimeXX and 22 for ToggleButton_PriorityXX
    If Mid(ItemControl.Name, 13, 2) = Mid(ToggleCtrl.Name, 22, 2) Then Set RelateControl_ToggleVsList = ItemControl: Exit Function
    End If ' 1. If TypeName(ItemControl) = "Label"
    Next ItemControl
End Function
```

***Problem:***

I get a null property when Setting the result:

```
Set RelateControl_ToggleVsList = ItemControl 'This is nullSet
```

[image]

***Debugging process:***
[image]
***Question:***

 How can I set a Control as a result of this function?

***EDIT:***

 Per request I add the whole Debugging in order to see where it is being called form

Calling Code

```
Private Sub ToggleButtons_Active()
Dim ItemControl As Control
Dim ItemTextBox As Variant
Dim TxtControl As String
    For Each ItemControl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ItemControl) = "ToggleButton" Then ' 1. If TypeName(ItemControl) = "ToggleButton"
    TxtControl = CStr(RelateControl_ToggleVsList(ItemControl).Value)
    If InStr(TextBox_Notes.Value, TxtControl) > 0 And TxtControl <> "" Then ItemControl.Value = True
    End If ' 1. If TypeName(ItemControl) = "ToggleButton"
    Next ItemControl
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error message and where does it pop up? Nothing in your code looks like it is obviously wrong. Perhaps the error is in how you are trying to use it in the calling code? Note that if the condition is never met then the return value will default to an empty object.

Comment: I just tested it using a dummy set of Controls (and getting rid of the `If` statement and just executing the `Set` for the first object in `Controls`) and a `MsgBox RelateControl_ToggleVsList(TextBox1).Name` correctly showed me the name of my first Control.  When you say that you get a Null property, do you just mean the returned ListBox's Value property is `Null`?

Comment: @JohnColeman I just added a SS of the debugger, @.YowE3k the ItemControl (which would be the object itself) is returning as null, hence the Err

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are doing the test (returning False) on the returned object.

Comment: Mid(ToggleCtrl.Name, 22, 2) is what each time? Is the condition met?

Comment: @YowE3K It's the same code that in the approach, I added the SS for where the Error can be seen

Comment: The `Null` is just saying that the Control's Value property is Null - it doesn't mean that the object is Nothing.  So you are returning a valid Control, but that Control hasn't yet had it's Value set.

Comment: @MacroMarc Yeah, If the ToogleCtrl1 is being analyzed set the ListBox1 so I can anlyze its text; if the ToogleCtrl2 is being analyzed set the ListBox2 and so on

Comment: @all Added the Gif to show my debugging process

Comment: So your function is showing that it is correctly returning a Control (probably the Control that you want).  (I.e. the very last "hover" before exiting the function shows that the return value has changed from `Nothing` to be a valid Control.)  Can you show us the code where you are invoking the function, because that is what is causing the error.

Comment: Maybe the calling code is passing an empty object

Comment: @JohnColeman - I suspect that the calling code is just using the returned Control's `Value` property, rather than doing something with the Control itself.

Comment: @.all Added the whole debugging; @YowE3k you're right, and I know I could change the function to return the text itself but, I rather to return the contorl just for future reference if I need to.

Comment: Seeing the animated gifs is not nearly as useful as seeing the actual calling code. The animated gifs are mostly distracting.

Comment: added the code as text

Comment: FWIW - the reason that you couldn't see the error in the debugger is that, after the Control was returned by the function, it's `Value` property was **immediately** used by the `CStr` which threw the error.  So you never got a chance in the debugger to look at the returned value **after** it was returned but before the error was thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution:***

The object itself is calling a property which does not belong to it (as intended).

[ListBox Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862699.aspx) does not show "Value" as its text, the real thing should have called it as:

```
TxtControl = CStr(RelateControl_ToggleVsList(ItemControl).List(0))CStr(RelateControl_ToggleVsList(ItemControl).List(0))
```

***Furthermore:***

Thanks to the solutions provided and the debugging process, I could notice even the object is Set in the function, it is shown as the "value" property of it while debugging.

Comment: ListBoxes do have a Value property - it is the value of the currently selected item.  (So if the 5th item is selected, it is equivalent to `.List(4)`.)

Comment: Yes it does, however, it was not used as intended and hence the error (I wanted to compare the text of it as stated in the background _b) If the ListBox1.Value has "mytext" then I have to relate it with ToggleButton1_) that's where my problem was, I was using the wrong property for this matter.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is occurring on your line which says

```
TxtControl = CStr(RelateControl_ToggleVsList(ItemControl).Value)
```

because the returned Control's `Value` property is currently `Null` which can't be cast to a String.

---

I recommend that you change `TxtControl` to be a `Variant` type, then say

```
TxtControl = RelateControl_ToggleVsList(ItemControl).Value
If IsNull(TxtControl) Then
    TxtControl = ""
Else
    TxtControl = CStr(TxtControl)
End If
```

---

Or you could define a Control object and then use it:

```
Dim MyControl As Control
MyControl = RelateControl_ToggleVsList(ItemControl)
If IsNull(MyControl.Value) Then
    TxtControl = ""
Else
    TxtControl = CStr(MyControl.Value)
End If
```

Comment: Looks like you nailed it. Good debugging.

Comment: @JohnColeman - I wish some of my own bugs were that easy to find!

Comment: Yes this is the approach I was thinking about of using if I could not set it as control, however, I rather to have it as control and then play with the properties as needed -today is a text tomorrow could be the height, etc-.

Comment: @Sgdva - see edit.  (With the "Control" version of the answer, you can leave `TxtControl` as type `String`, as it won't need to be able to hold the `Null` - it will always be set to a valid `String` so you won't need to declare it as a `Variant`.)

Comment: This lead me to the real solution, I saw my problem, dah long day I guess.